# Background images not showing up on some computers

Tags: css, background

I'm having trouble finding the root of this problem. I'm hoping maybe someone here has come across it before. For some reason background images are not showing up on some computers. For instance the code below works fine on my computer, from all browsers - when viewed from my friend's computer though it doesn't show up at all.

I've opened safari's web inspector on their computer and when I look the css via that inspector, there is a small, triangular, yellow caution symbol next to the background rule, but nothing denoting why it's there.

Is there something blatantly wrong with this rudimentary css rule? - Driving me banana's!

```
background: url("images/about-header.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 15% / cover rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

As always, thanks for any and all help with this.

Comment: can you give us some more code and share a [jsFiddle.net](http://jsFiddle.net) for us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem is I can't seem to replicate the problem. There's no other code affecting it, just a simple background rule, but never works on these few computers.

Comment: Are you sure that your image path is correct? It seems that you are declaring wrongly as from your problem stated

Comment: the path is correct, it shows up fine on most computers - just not on a few. In which way is it declared wrong though? Perhaps declaring it differently would solve it.

Comment: are you sure about your shorthand? try using `background-image` and `background-repeat` and `background-position` etc. and see if you still have the problem

Comment: You mentioned "never works on these few computers" is it only a certain set of computers?? maybe there is an issue with devices instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue very similar to this, actually almost identical. I managed to sort it by not using shorthand css. Expand the css out completely and then check that out.

This worked for me perfectly

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @KM123 I'll be able to test it on the other computers this afternoon. If that works, I'll accept this.

Comment: No problem my friend also when testing it - Don't forget to clear the cache as it could load the previous style :)

Comment: That was it - now I have about 20 sites to go through and change all my shorthand to long form. Glad I found out now instead of in 5 years from now! Thanks!